# get response from server without page refresh

Tags: ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fun1(){

var xmlHttp;
try {// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  
} catch (e) {// Internet Explorer
try {
xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
try {
 xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
 alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
 return false;
}
}
}

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
var respText = xmlHttp.responseText.split('<body>');
elem.innerHTML = respText[1].split('</body>')[0];
$("#st-content").show();
}
}
var ur='Tips.action';
xmlHttp.open("GET", ur, true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}
</script>
```

Actually i have 2 jsps.one for inserting and another for viewing the inserted records.
The inserting jsp page appears in popup.after submitting the form the inserted record should be viewed in another jsp without page refresh.
How can i achieve this?please anyone guide me to complete this task

Comment: You'll need to implement some sort of listener. While the file on it's own will require a page refresh, have a look at `Live.js`. This will make head requests to your server, and when something has changed, it will do an automatic refresh. Except instead of the refresh, you can set it to make an AJAX request. [Here](http://livejs.com/) is the documentation and website.

Answer (score 0):

ajax success response you can replace response text to the popup current html code or a div code

Comment: Please expand your answer. In its current form it is not very helpful.